# How to estimate the prior variance in mixed model with complete separation?

Tags: r, mixed-model, binomial-distribution, glmm, lme4-nlme

I have a reciprocal transplant experiment with larvae from four locations and their substrates with three replicates (blocks). A significant interaction between location and substrate would suggest local adaptation.

I would like to construct a mixed model to test two things: 1) if survival is greater in 'locals' versus foreigners, and 2) if survival is greater for genotypes in their "home" locations versus "away" (substrates). I would use Tukey posthoc tests to determine the above two criteria for local adaptation.

Sample dataset:

```
structure(list(Location = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", 
"C", "D"), class = "factor"), Substrate = structure(c(2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), Replicate = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 
2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 
2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 
3, 1), Survival = structure(c(5, 10, 14, 18, 27, 18, 1, 22, 9, 
30, 18, 30, 25, 27, 18, 19, 21, 19, 19, 23, 23, 4, 17, 19, 9, 
15, 9, 19, 27, 8, 9, 7, 13, 29, 26, 8, 22, 18, 15, 18, 19, 29, 
15, 30, 30, 30, 0, 0, 25, 20, 16, 12, 3, 12, 29, 8, 21, 0, 12, 
0, 5, 3, 12, 11, 9, 11, 11, 7, 7, 26, 13, 11, 21, 15, 21, 11, 
3, 22, 21, 23, 17, 1, 4, 22, 8, 12, 15, 12, 11, 1, 15, 0, 0, 
0, 30, 30), .Dim = c(48L, 2L))), .Names = c("Location", "Substrate", 
"Replicate", "Survival"), row.names = c(NA, 48L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have constructed a mixed model as follows:

```
require(lme4)
Survival.model.1 <- glmer(Survival ~ Location + Substrate + Location:Substrate  + (1|Replicate), data = model_data, family=binomial)
```

When I run the model I get the following:

```
Warning messages: 1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :   unable to evaluate scaled gradient 
                  2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv, : Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 1 negative eigenvalues
```

The summary of the model results shows that one of the effects has a very large standard error:

```
Fixed effects:
                      Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)             1.9591     0.4257   4.602 4.19e-06 ***
LocationB              -1.0619     0.3926  -2.705  0.00684 **
LocationC              -1.5271     0.3844  -3.973 7.09e-05 ***
LocationD              -0.7680     0.4017  -1.912  0.05586 .
SubstrateB             -2.5875     0.3882  -6.665 2.65e-11 ***
SubstrateC             -0.9485     0.3957  -2.397  0.01653 *
SubstrateD             -2.1938     0.3832  -5.724 1.04e-08 ***
LocationB:SubstrateB    0.9046     0.5088   1.778  0.07544 .
LocationC:SubstrateB    1.5780     0.4995   3.159  0.00158 **
LocationD:SubstrateB   -0.2139     0.5399  -0.396  0.69190
LocationB:SubstrateC    1.3718     0.5280   2.598  0.00938 **
LocationC:SubstrateC    0.6604     0.5026   1.314  0.18885
LocationD:SubstrateC    0.6546     0.5240   1.249  0.21157
LocationB:SubstrateD    1.9798     0.5039   3.929 8.52e-05 ***
LocationC:SubstrateD    1.1843     0.4958   2.389  0.01691 *
LocationD:SubstrateD   21.5690  2915.9603   0.007  0.99410
--- Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
Correlation matrix not shown by default, as p = 16 > 12. Use print(x, correlation=TRUE)  or      vcov(x)     if you need it
convergence code: 0 unable to evaluate scaled gradient Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 1 negative eigenvalues
```

I believe this is due to the fact that for the three observations of the LocationD x SubstrateD there is 100% survival, while this does not occur anywhere else in our study.

I have found a couple of similar examples [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/132677/binomial-glmm-with-a-categorical-variable-with-full-successes) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38493/how-to-deal-with-quasi-complete-separation-in-a-logistic-glmm) an excellent explanation with examples by Ben Bolker [here](https://rpubs.com/bbolker/glmmchapter) of complete separation or maybe it is called [Hauck-Donner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18340674/how-can-a-se-be-above-1000-in-a-multilevel-logistic-regression) effect.

If I follow the example Ben Bolker suggests using:

```
require(blme)
Survival.model.2 <- bglmer(Survival ~ Location + Substrate + Location:Substrate  + (1|Replicate), data = model_data, family=binomial, fixef.prior = normal(cov = diag(X,16)))
```

Due to my relatively new experiences with mixed-models, **I am unsure how to estimate the prior variance of each parameter (X) in the above code. Or alternatively, are there reasonable default boundary values that can be provided for these parameters?**

Any suggestions on how to solve my problem with complete separation is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With help from others, I have figured out the estimate for prior variance.

```
Survival.model.2 <- bglmer(Survival ~ -1 + Location:Substrate + (1|Replicate), model_data, family=binomial, fixef.prior = normal(cov = diag(7,16)), control=glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa"))
```

In this case though I am still left with the question of whether the random effect is truly important to the model and whether the more simple approach would be to use a Firth logistic regression model?